# What should I know about Morphological processing

Tags: image-processing

i'm studying my first year as technical student , and we are studying image processing, so last week we got delivered a topic to work on : Morphological processing /opening
, i'm trying to dig deeper in internet but i lost in the amount of informations as a beginner, I still can't figure out what is that (morphology processing) all about.
Can you give me a hand with this?